# Error when installing the modules of my project in angular

Tags: angular

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: erpinfo@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@16.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^16.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"15.2.9" from @angular/animations@15.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^15.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-24T19_01_32_599Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-24T19_01_32_599Z-debug-0.log
```

I wanted to install the modules of my project but I had this problem

Answer (score 0):

Check `package.json`: Open your project's `package.json` file and review the versions of Angular packages specified in the `dependencies` or `devDependencies` section. Ensure that all Angular packages have compatible versions.

Remove node_modules and package-lock.json: Sometimes, dependency resolution issues can be resolved by removing your project's node_modules directory and package-lock.json file, and then running npm install again:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

try this and if then not work send the `package.json` file